# Do a collection of black body emitters emit radiation in synchronization with each other?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation, coherence

Just read that all bodies at temperature T>0K emit radiation whose spectral characteristics depend on the temperature of the body. I am thinking of a macroscopic body as a collection of several tiny black body emitters(atoms/molecules?). Is this thinking valid and if it is, is there any phase synchronization among all these emitters? Now let's say this body is made up of chromophores and I raise the temperature of the body by shining pulsed laser light, will the emission be synchronized now amongst the different constituent chromophores?

Answer (score 0):

Blackbody emmitters are of macroscopic dimensions, there is no black body model  for individual atoms or molecules ( [chromophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromophore) a a chemistry definition ). Black body radiation is one of the main reasons quantum mechanics was needed to describe the microcosm. Have a [look here.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html)

The black body radiation is built up by all possible electromagnetic emissions in  a black body, and the formula is approximately followed by real bodies. Look for example at the [spectrum of the sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Solar_spectrum_en.svg), which still shows departure of the black body formula  due to spectral lines (not chromophores as the energy is very large in the sun). [The best fit](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Cmbr.svg/300px-Cmbr.svg.png) to the black body radiation comes from the background microwave radiation.

> Now let's say this body is made up of chromophores and I raise the temperature of the body by shining pulsed laser light, will the emission be synchronized now amongst the different constituent chromophores?

If you shine a pulsed laser,why would the reactions not be synchronized? But it is not because of black body and the temperature the material is raised to, which you will understand if you read up on black body.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection of blackbodies, these will after some time be in thermal equilibrium with each other, after which they can be thought of as emitting as one single blackbody.